# Update from select query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have used the following query to insert values in table

```
INSERT INTO `tbl1` SELECT * FROM tbl2
```

Over here tb1 is a temp table.

Now, I want something like this

```
UPDATE `my_table` SELECT * FROM tbl1
```

I know that the syntax for update is Update tbl SET cols = vals
But can we have something like the insert query above ?

Thanks.

Comment: don't you think so that you have given insufficient data

Answer (score 4):

You can do`Insert with Select` but not `Update with Select`. But still possible by using JOIN within `UPDATE`.

```
UPDATE table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.col1 = t2.col2, t1.col2 = t2.col2
```

Comment: I think you mean `SET t1.col1 = t2.col1`

Comment: Thanks @Rahul but it's only just an example. I was trying to illustrate the `format of join` not the data assignment because what if col1 and col2 from t1 should have the value of col2 from t2?

Answer (score 3):

You can join your `tbl1` table with `my_table` using the multiple-table `UPDATE` syntax:

```
UPDATE my_table JOIN tbl1 ON ***join_condition***
  SET my_table.foo = tbl1.bar, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
update my_table join tbl1 on my_table.id = tbl1.id
set my_table.Vaal= tbl1.vaal
```

Comment: Yaa, that's actually SQL Server syntax, not mysql. though they are almost same.